# Why doesn’t Windows 10 show a video thumbnail when encoding from x265 to x264?

Tags: windows-10, video, ffmpeg

I have been re-encoding video files for some time now and I do not want to stream x265 so I merely do an encode.

This time after an encode from x265 to x264 there is no video thumbnail in my Windows 10 Explorer.

What I did:

```
ffmpeg -i "%n.mkv" -c:v libx264 -c:a ac3 -c:s copy -b:v 4096k -b:a 384k -map_metadata -1 -metadata:s:v:0 language=LAN -metadata:s:a:0 language=LAN %%~na.mkv
```

Video plays as it should, stream size is as it should be. The only thing that is different is the MediaInfo video output `Bits/(Pixel*Frame) : 0.086`.

As I said everything works fine… But there is no thumbnail. I would like to know why there is no thumbnail.

Comment: Windows 10 by default does not have native x264 or x265 codec support.  [Explaination](https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/84101-x265-hevc-video-not-playing-thumbnails.html).  If you install something like VLC you should see a difference.  You can get the codec for [free](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/hevc-video-extensions-from-device-manufacturer/9n4wgh0z6vhq?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) directly from Microsoft.  Even with the HEVC codec directly from Microsoft, it might still require VLC, for the thumbnails to work.

Comment: Like I said I've done this for some time (2 years). I have VLC installed.

Comment: You have associated the file extension with a compatible player?

Comment: The file ext is mkv and codec is libx264... video plays fine e- no proplems at all. I would just like to know why windows doesn't show a default thumbnail.
I wonder ; if I go and delete all thumbnails, this will somehow reset the videofile in the index.

Comment: Just deleted 877mb and it didn't work - all other thumbnails are regerating - but no thumbnail for this one video.

Comment: My default video player is MPC-HC x64

Comment: I highly suspect the problem is the player in that case.

Comment: I understand your concern in that matter, I'm now going to try to to make VLC my default player.

Edit: the video file thumbnail/icon is now a cone.

Comment: I actually suspect reencoding the video with a lower video bitrate would work. NOT using -c:v libx264...

Comment: Still no thumbnail.
Just did:
ffmpeg -ss 60 -t 120 -i "%%n.mkv" -c:a copy -map 0  "Done/%%~na.mkv"

Still no thumbnail on video. Video codec and bitrate is now completely up to ffmpeg.

Comment: Show the complete log from the ffmpeg command (just run a single instance, not batch).

Comment: How do I submit that? I'm a complete newb and I have a 500KB txt file..

Comment: 500KB seems excessive. You can use Firefox Send or whatever you prefer and provide a link here.